# how to save value of color picker into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

how to save value of color picker into mysql,,i have code to change background but i want to save the value of color picker into my sql using php script..help me please..
Thanks before ^^

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Control Color</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload = init;
         function init () {
            var formulir = document.getElementById("formulir");
            formulir.onsubmit = function() {
               var color1 = document.getElementById("color1").value;
               document.bgColor = color1;
               return false; // Batalkan submit
            }      
         }
      </script>
      <style>
         label {
            float: left;
            width: 120px;
         }  
         p { clear: both; } 
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="formulir" action="">
         <fieldset>
            <legend>change background:</legend>
            <p>
               <label>color:</label>
               <input type="color" id="color1" name="color1">
            </p>
            <input type="submit"  id="button" value="Process">
         </fieldset>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use ajax for this

Comment: What have you done on your server side (inside your PHP script?). It looks like your JavaScript is trapping the submit action preventing the form from posting to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are preventing the form to be send, so I guess you dont want the page to be reloaded. That means you have to use AJAX. Since you used pure javascript I will use it too, but I recommend using a framework for basic projects :)

To your javascript script add something like

```
function sendPostToPHP( color ){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) var ajaxPostRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
      else var ajaxPostRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5   

    ajaxPostRequest.open("POST", "YOURSCRIPT.php", false);

    ajaxPostRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxPostRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (ajaxPostRequest.status == 200) {
                //data was revived successfully.
            }
        }
    }

    var data = "color=" + color;
    //setting header is important - otherwise PHP will not load it into $_POST:
    ajaxPostRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxPostRequest.send(data);        
}
```

And then just after your line `var color1 = document.getElementById("color1").value;` add something like:

```
sendPostToPHP(color1);
```

Your PHP could then look like this:

```
if( empty($_POST['color']) ) exit("No color recived.");

try {
    $db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host=YOURHOSTNAME;dbname=YOURDBNAME', 'YOURDBUSER', 'YOURDBPASSWORD');
    $db_connection -> query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); //optional
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // DB CONNECTION ERROR
} 
//example query:
$query = $db_connection->prepare( "INSERT INTO colors (color) VALUES (:color)" ); 
$query->bindValue(':color', $_POST['color'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->execute();
```

## EDITED & TESTED

I've corrected the code and tested it a bit - it works now :)